# Google Maps v3 sync and update markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I spent this morning searching something simple but same time flexible to use for courier delivery like small companies or groups / to organize them selves and order/destinations in a map. While I gave up for searching after few hours going through trillion posts :) and reviewing many commercial software's. I spent last hour making my own and got my self working application however many questions raised in my mind so I was thinking to start opensource project of it and with this short intro and following code to share it with you guys, hoping that perhaps I find some good answers or great ideas. How to make it efficient to use on any browser, any device including over Mobile Internet .  :).
I'm stuck with finding proper way how to keep map up to date basically in real-time.
setInterval!? Anyhow all my browsers freeze and stop updating after some period of time while I expect it to run 24/7/365 if needed. I would really appreciated if somebody can lead me at least right direction to make this sync more stable.
thanks advance!

**Clobal Gonfig**

```
/***********************************
* Config
************************************/
/* Master Server    */  var master_server       = {
    url             : 'https://0.0.0.0/',
    status          : false,
    connectionFail  : "Connection to Master Server Failed"
}
/* Slave Server     */  var slave_server        = {
    url             : 'https://0.0.0.0/',
    status          : false,
    connectionFail  : "Connection to Slave Server Failed"
}
/* Sync controller  */  var sync_controller     = '/datasync/';
/* Sync actions     */  
var sync_action         = {
    updateLatLng    : 'updatewithgeo/'
}
/***********************************/
var car             = false;
var order           = false;
var order_icon      = "static_icon.png";
var customMsg       = {
    PositionFail    : "Because Default lat lng and getCurrentPosition are not set app will not try to sync! It will try again shotwhile"
}
// Can define default lat lng
var lat         = false;
var lng         = false;
/***********************************/
```

**App**

```
function syncData()
{
//Temporarly clearing markers to avoid marker[$i] to be duplicated if position is changed
if(markers){$('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');}
// Exhange data with server
$('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {
    if ( status === 'OK' ) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lng = position.coords.longitude;
    }
    if (!lat){
        console.log(customMsg.PositionFail);
        setTimeout('syncData()', 10000);
        throw new Error(customMsg.PositionFail);
        return;
    }
    $.post(master_server.url+sync_controller+sync_action.updateLatLng, {latlng : lat+"@"+lng}, function(data, Server_1_Status) {

        if(Server_1_Status != 'OK')
        {
            // If request to master server then here would be place to connect to slave server(s)
            console.log(master_server.connectionFail);
            setTimeout('syncData()', 10000);
            throw new Error(master_server.connectionFail);
            return;
        }
        // If there is no errors
        $.each( data.couriers, function(i, courier) {
            // If markers are identified correctly when they are returned from server
            // then addMarker should only add new markers and 
            // existing markers shuld be updated (setPosition)

            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(courier.latitude, courier.longitude), 
                'bounds': true,
                'icon' : courier.icon,
                'title' : courier.name
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': courier.content }, this);
            });
        });
        $.each( data.orders, function(i, order) {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(order.latitude, order.longitude), 
                'bounds': true,
                'title' : order.address,
                'icon' : ""
            }).click(function() {
                // Populating order view and forms to take / confirm delivery and send digital signature
                $('#OrderViewTitle').html('<h1>'+order.orderID+order.address+'</h1>');
                $('#OrderData').html('<p><b>'+order.customerID+'</b><br><b>Order:</b>'+order.salesorder+'</p>');
                document.getElementById('TakeDelivery').value = order.orderID;
                document.getElementById('DeliveryComplete').value = order.orderID;
                $('#OrderView').popup("open");
            });
        });
    }, "json");

    $('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh');
    setTimeout('syncData()', 10000);
}); 
}
$(document).ready(function() {
courierApp.add(function() {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function() {
        syncData();
});
    }).load();
});
```

Comment: The first thing to do is change `setInterval('syncData()', 10000);` for `setTimeout(syncData, 10000);`. With setInterval, it's maybe not surprising that it crashes. setTimeout should give it a fighting chance.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that :) thanks for pointing it out. I'm more back-end developer so such thing's happen once and a while

Comment: You would probably have a few laughs at my server-side code!

Comment: Does changing 
`$.post(master_server.url+sync_controller+sync_action.updateLatLng, {latlng : lat+"@"+lng}, function(data, Server_1_Status) {...});` to

`$.post(master_server.url+sync_controller+sync_action.updateLatLng, {latlng : lat+"@"+lng}).done(function(data, Server_1_Status) {
  ...
});` help anything?

Comment: `.done()` is considered better style, otherwise no difference. You may be able to move the $.post success function out of `syncData()` and name it eg. `postSuccess`. This would avoid having to define the function at every iteration and would allow the post statement to be simplified, vis `$.post(master_server.url + sync_controller + sync_action.updateLatLng, postSuccess, "json");`.

Comment: If you want to reload your page, use this `$.mobile.changePage( url, { reloadPage: true, transition: "none"} );` this will force the page to reload with new data. you can set timer for it. _url_ is the page's link, should be `""`.

Comment: @Omar no I don't want to refresh my page.... Thanks for trying. I'm  interested to update ONLY needed data!

Comment: Maybe you should check out WebSockets http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/ and http://html5demos.com/web-socket

Comment: @Mr.Pohoda thanks for that comment. That's so cool, I think exploring that option meets my expectations about future of the web...